# Create a BoxGeometry 16x16 Grid relative to viewport size with Three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

The question goes as simple as it can, the title pretty much describes what I'm trying to do.

I'm new to Three.js and WebGL, I more or less understand the basics of creating a Cube but when it comes to what I'm trying to do I'm at loss.

I'm basically using this pen as reference while I learn: https://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/vOEKzw as it does what I want without it being relative to screen size

```js
var tick = 0,
  smallestDimension = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
  viewportWidth = smallestDimension,
  viewportHeight = smallestDimension,
  worldWidth = 100,
  worldHeight = 100,
  rows = 30,
  cols = 30,
  tileWidth = worldWidth / cols,
  tileHeight = worldHeight / rows,
  FOV = 90,
  scene = new THREE.Scene(),
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    FOV,
    viewportWidth / viewportHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  ),
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  }),
  plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(worldWidth, worldHeight, 1),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0x222222
    })
  ),
  cubes = new THREE.Object3D(),
  spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff),
  ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666);

renderer.setSize(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

scene.add(plane);
scene.add(cubes);
scene.add(spotLight);
scene.add(ambientLight);

for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    var width = tileWidth,
      height = tileHeight,
      dx = (cols / 2 - x),
      dy = (rows / 2 - y),
      depth = 1 + (20 - Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)) / 4,
      xBase = -worldWidth / 2 + x * tileWidth + tileWidth / 2,
      yBase = -worldHeight / 2 + y * tileHeight + tileHeight / 2,
      zBase = depth / 2,
      cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          color: 'rgb(' + ~~((y / rows) * 255) + ', ' + ~~((x / cols) * 255) + ', 255)',
          shininess: 50
        })
      );
    cube.position.set(
      xBase,
      yBase,
      zBase
    );
    cube.castShadow = true;
    cube.receiveShadow = true;
    cube.zBase = zBase;
    cube.zScaleTarget = 1;
    cubes.add(cube);
  }
}

plane.position.set(0, 0, 0);
plane.castShadow = false;
plane.receiveShadow = true;

camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);

spotLight.position.set(0, 0, 100);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 0.1;
spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.1;

function step() {
  spotLight.position.x = Math.sin(tick / 100) * (worldWidth / 2);
  spotLight.position.y = Math.cos(tick / 100) * (worldHeight / 2);

  cubes.traverse(function(cube) {
    if (cube instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      if (Math.abs(cube.scale.z - cube.zScaleTarget) > 0.001) {
        cube.scale.z += (cube.zScaleTarget - cube.scale.z) * 0.05;
      } else {
        cube.zScaleTarget = 1 + Math.random() * 10;
      }
      cube.position.z = cube.geometry.parameters.depth / 2 * cube.scale.z;
    }
  });

  tick++;
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  step();
  render();
}

loop();

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
```

```
worldWidth = 100,
worldHeight = 100,
rows = 30,
cols = 30,
tileWidth = worldWidth / cols,
tileHeight = worldHeight / rows,
```

I see it uses this to set the size of the tiles that he lates uses in the loop:

```
...
var width = tileWidth,
    height = tileHeight,
    dx = ( cols / 2 - x ),
    dy = ( rows / 2 - y ),
    depth = 1 + ( 20 - Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy ) ) / 4,
    xBase = -worldWidth / 2 + x * tileWidth + tileWidth / 2,
    yBase = -worldHeight / 2 + y * tileHeight + tileHeight / 2,
...
```

How would I draw this tiles across the whole viewport so its similar to:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What about using [`GridHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/GridHelper)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I thought about it but can I interact with each individual cell with grid helper?

Answer (score 0):

Rather then to take `Math.min` use this in line number 2 `smallestDimension = Math.max( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )`
It will automatically cover your screen size. 
If you want you can change `rows = 10` and `col = 10`

Comment: Additionally, it's good to adjust camera's FOV. Or to put the camera closer to the grid of boxes.